# Get all POJO Classes (in deep.model class, entity)

Tags: java, package

I am trying to create a good solution, which identifies all classes (in all cases in suffix is "model").
Now i iterate over the projekt packages and look after "model" and make some exclusions.
Then i have a Path Object, which i can convert to File Path.toFile().
I am interesting of knowing the best way to get the fullqualified model class e.g. Cars.BMW for Class.forName().
There are also few Util Libraries like for Files etc.
I dont know the libraries in deepth (apache in most times)
How would you do this?

Comment: Please paste your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be a better solution to use a [Marker Interface](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2012/01/what-is-marker-interfaces-in-java-and.html) or a custom [Annotation](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/).

This way you can easily identify which classes are model classes.

**I would actually not rely just on the name!**

---

Libraries that could help you:

- https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections
- https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner/wiki